# What would happen if the Linux kernel deleted itself?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

What would happen if the Linux kernel deleted itself? Will there be a moment when it could no longer delete files because rm or the program used for deletion has been deleted too?

Regards.

Comment: Was reading an blog from a gut who basically did this and managed to recover from. Quite an interesting read - http://fendrich.se/blog/2010/08/27/rescuing-hosed-system-using-only-bash/

Answer (score 3):

The question is (apart from being off-topic) somewhat wrong in itself, as `rm` is not part of the kernel, but either a shell built-in or a separate user-level program. Admittedly, `rm` uses a syscall provided by the kernel, but that is irrelevant.

The kernel itself is loaded from a compressed image and locked in RAM. It does not matter whether you delete the compressed image until you reboot (which will fail with the boot loader giving you a message like "vmlinuz not found"). You have no way of removing the kernel from RAM (well, other than rebooting...).

Also, for the most part, it does not even matter whether you delete a file, including a running program's executable anyway (if we may be so daunting as to call the kernel a "program" for a moment) under Linux, because deleting a file merely removes the link, not the file. It is a Windows-typical assumption that deleting a file does evil, destructive things.
Under Unix-like systems, it is perfectly possible to delete (or replace) a program while it is running, and it will not cause any problems at all. You will remove the name in the filesystem, that's all. Any open descriptors will remain valid until the last one is closed, the original file will stay intact as-is for any observer who obtained a handle earlier, and it will be "gone" for everyone trying to get at it later.